# Nib file does not load from UITabBarViewController

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, interface-builder, uitabbarcontroller

I've tried almost all the possible permutations... I'm trying to make something like this:

http://www.amateurinmotion.com/articles/2009/01/24/creating-uitabbarcontroller-based-app-using-interfacebuilder.html

It's fairly simple and I tried running the program and it works. Now I'm trying to customise my current app so that it uses IB to load the xib file. My view hierarchy is like this:

[image]

So what I did is I selected the view controller and then I go to the view controller attributes and set the nib name to be a nib file name. I also changed the view controller identity to load my custom class.

Comment: there is one warning in the IB at the bottom right of the above window. Check it out first.

Comment: ignore it, it's just saying I have a conflicting label and I've fixed it =) it was very late at night...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it... It turns out that I have an extra layer of UIView in my view controllers... All good now!